# core dump is not generating

Tags: linux, centos, coredump

I am trying to get core dump generated when java program crashes. I followed instructions to enable the core dump. I am triggering the crash using `kill -s SIGSEGV PID`

```
I have enabled ulimit to unlimited

$ ulimit -c
unlimited

pattern of core file 
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
/var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.%u.%e.%p

$ pwd
/var/lib/systemd/coredump

This directory is writable
$ ls -lrt core*
ls: cannot access core*: No such file or directory

I have also set suid_dumpable to 2
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
2

There is enough space available in the disk
$ df -kh .
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      100G   20G   81G  20% /
```

Could you please help me to get through this? I am using `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708`

Comment: Does `kill` generate any error?  Are you passing `PID` as shown or the actual numeric ID for the target process?  (BTW, see `pkill`).  Maybe the target process resets the resource limit to 0?  Also try attaching the target process with `strace -o /tmp/trace.out -p <PID> &`, then run `kill`

Comment: Please can you try a different process, for example `sleep 1000 & kill -SEGV $!`, and see whether that dumps core. This should hopefully help distinguish between whether processes in general are not dumping core, or your application has installed a `SIGSEGV` handler. If the latter, see if using `SIGABRT` instead makes any difference.

Comment: @Milag I am actually using numeric PID, attaching strace gives me the stack trace but kill after that is still not generating core dump

Comment: @alaniwi Thank you, let me try sending SIGABRT signal. I am not sure about the application if it has any handlers for these signals.

Comment: Related: what numbers are reported with `grep core /proc/<target-pid>/limits`? Also try starting the program with `strace -e getrlimit,setrlimit <program> &`; any output with `RLIMIT_CORE`?

Comment: `ulimit -c unlimited` must be run in the same bash in which the program to be run.